# Why does a point mass receive double the velocity when colliding with a moving wall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A point mass slides with speed v on a frictionless horizontal surface between two fixed parallel walls,
initially a distance L apart. It bounces between the walls perfectly elastically. You move one of the
walls towards the other by a distance 0.01L, with speed 0.0001v. What is the final speed of the
point mass?

You can find the solution at problem 7
https://www.aapt.org/physicsteam/upload/2021_Fma_Solutions.pdf

I'm having trouble understanding the solution. It says that every collision the point mass's speed increase by 2*0.0001v. Why does it increase two times?

Answer (score 4):

First consider a stationary wall. If I slide a point mass towards it with velocity $v$, it will bounce back such that it velocity becomes $-v$. As a small note, the magnitude of the speed hasn't changed since $|-v|-|v|=0$.

Now imagine the wall is moving towards the left with speed $-u$ ($u$ is positive). What is the new speed now? We can change reference frames such that the wall is stationary, perform the bounce and finally change back reference frames to get our answer.

1. Initially the speed of the point mass is $v_\text{mass}=v$ and the wall is moving at $v_\text{wall}=-u$
2. After changing reference frames such that the wall is stationary we get $v_\text{mass}=v+u$ and $ v_\text{wall}=0$
3. After the bounce we have $v_\text{mass}=-v-u$ and $ v_\text{wall}=0$
4. After changing back reference frames we have $v_\text{mass}=-v-2u$ and $ v_\text{wall}=-u$

The total speed of the mass has been increased by $2u$, since the absolute value is now larger: $|-v-2u|-|v|=2u$

Note that changing reference frames works by adding a constant velocity to every object.

Answer (score 1):

They are treating the wall as effectively infinite mass. Thus, for collisions with the moving wall, the center of momentum frame is the moving wall. In this frame, the sliding object starts with some velocity V(n) (for the n'th collision) and finishes with -V(n).

However, in the frame of the lab where we are measuring things, the object starts with a closing velocity V(n) + V_wall.

Remember that it finishes moving away from the wall with a relative velocity of the same but negative. That is, relative to the wall it is moving away from the wall at V(n) + V_wall.

So that means that in the lab frame it goes from V(n) towards the wall to V(n) + 2 * V_wall away from the wall.

Answer (score 1):

the equations for  two point masses $~m_1~,m_2~$ collied perfectly elastically are:

$$v_1=\frac{2\,m_2\,u_2+u_1(m_1-m_2)}{m_1+m_2}\\
v_2=\frac{2\,m_1\,u_1+u_2(m_2-m_1)}{m_1+m_2}
$$

where $~u_i~$ are the initial velocities and $~v_i~$ the final velocities.

your case $~u_1=0~,u_2=v~$
and $~m_2\mapsto \infty~$

you obtain

$$v_1=2\,v\quad,v_2=v$$

---

$$\lim_{m_2\mapsto\infty} v_1=\frac{2\,v}{1+\frac{m_1}{m_2}}\\
\lim_{m_2\mapsto\infty} v_2=\frac{v\left(1-\frac{m_1}{m_2}\right)}{1+\frac{m_1}{m_2}}$$